# URL to PDF conversion on OS X

Tags: macos, bash, pdf

I am trying to create a bash function called url2pdf:

```
wget -O "$1" | /System/Library/Printers/Libraries/convert | open -a Preview
```

However, whenever I try and execute this, I get:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: “STDOUT”

[ <=>                                                                          ] 0 --.-K/s   in 0s      


Cannot write to “-” (Broken pipe).
```

So I am guessing there is something wrong with my pipe redirection.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I normally wouldn't comment on such an old post, but this one was a relatively high result when I googled for "url to pdf" so I thought it was worth mentioning: 'convert' is no longer part of Mac OS X 10.8 but you can get much of the same thing accomplished with `cupsfilter` (part of OS X) but the args are different. Most notably, it takes one file as an arg, and sends its output to stdout, so you have to redirect to a file if you want to save to PDF. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `convert` program doesn't seem to like STDIN streams that come from pipes:

```
ian-cs-macbook-pro:temp ianc$ echo "Hello world" | /System/Library/Printers/Libraries/convert
Usage: convert [ options ]

Options:
...snipped...
```

Try using TMPDIR instead:

```
function url2pdf {
    HTML=$TMPDIR`basename $1`'.html'
    PDF=`basename $1`'.pdf'
    wget -O $HTML $1
    /System/Library/Printers/Libraries/convert -f $HTML -o $PDF
    rm -f $HTML
    open -a Preview $PDF
}
```

That's crude, but it works. You can tweak to suit your tastes for saving the PDF on disk or not.

Comment: Hooray for process substitution. `/System/.../convert -f <(wget ...) -o >(open -a Preview)`

Comment: @Ignacio: Nice. New trick learned. Didn't know you could bracket like that to sub a process for a file name. Difference between your output and mine is mine produces a rendered view of the page, yours is a PDF version of the HTML source. I wonder what rendered the page in my version? Preview?

Comment: `convert` probably can't tell what it is since there's no extension to parse.

Comment: @Ignacio: with your sol'n quitting Preview doesn't get you back the prompt. It stays held by convert with the message: Cannot write to `-' (Broken pipe).

Comment: @Ignacio: cool. I didn't know convert would render like that. Neat program.